# TVS diode replacement - top marking P450 DEM

Tags: diodes, identification, tvs

I got a Hikvision camera DS-2CD2332-I that was mistakenly connected to 48 V power supply instead of 12 V. I checked the board and found a TVS diode is getting hot. The power supply LED was blinking at some regular interval while connected.

I removed the diode, connected the camera and surprisingly it worked! So I guess, before using it for surveillance, I need to get new part instead of fried one, so another V spike doesn't kill the board.

I have a problem identifying that diode. All I could find is manufacturer is BrightKing, but can't get any specs about power/voltage... Markings are P450 DEM

Any hint? What would be proper replacement?

Thanks

[image: diode]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this data sheet](http://brightking.pulseelectronics.com/uploadfiles/file/TSS/2017081808533853383918.pdf), the DEM package marking code matches part number SMDJ15CA.

[image]

Comment: Thanks crj11, I'll check this.