# Growatt inverter TVS diode identification

Tags: identification, tvs

I have a Growatt inverter which I re-connected incorrectly and it killed a few of my mosfets, which I have already identified, however I have a few TVS diodes which I am having a hard time identifying.
I have found this [relevant post link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520114/tvs-diode-replacement-top-marking-p450-dem) for which a table with packaging/names but have not been able to find such catalog.

Readings I can see:
PKMH / GGM and the logo is for "brightking"
I know it is a TVS as in the board is numbers 8 of htem as TVS1,TVS2...TVS8 and they seem to be in parallel with the blown mosfets.

Dimensions 7mmx8mm

Would appreciate if anyone would direct me to which diode this is or a suitable replacement.

[image: photo showing unknown component]

[image]

Comment: The Bourns logo is prominent, so search that site. You can narrow down the possibilities based on the package size. I’m pretty sure it is a TVS device.

Comment: Appreciate everyone's comments, I have added all details requested.

Comment: I just googled brightking ggm. First hit. SMCJ64A

Comment: So maybe Brightking is a Littelfuse copycat, in which case you could go for the Littelfuse part instead.

Comment: @Kartman seems I was overcomplicating things, and adding a ton of extra words to my search, I truly appreciate all your help!

Comment: Did you figure out it's specs, I'm trying to find the exact same one.